# Fetching an Xml Listobject depending on the value in one of its keys

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

I am currently going through an xml data,

```
<datas>
    <data>
        <key1>ABC</key1>
        <key2>def</key2>
    </data>
    <data>
        <key1>PQR</key1>
        <key2>xyz</key2>
    </data>
</datas>
```

Here i want to fetch the value in tag **key2** from the data where the **key1** is **PQR**

I had used the xpath expression

`//datas/data[last()]/key2`

but this one will work only if the last data is having the value.

what will be the xpath expression to fetch the same?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
/datas/data[key1="PQR"]/key2
```